# Как обслуживать оба протокола http и https в Node.js-приложениях без фреймворков?

Tags: node.js, http, https

Модуль [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) не поддерживает протокол HTTPS, точно так же, как модуль [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) не поддерживает HTTPS. Отсюда возникает сразу много проблем.

Например мы переносим сайт с HTTP на HTTPS или наоборот. Переписывать приложение? Но в данном вопросе хотел бы рассмотреть другую задачу. Допустим, мы обслуживаем запросы как с HTTP, так и HTTPS. На основе какой концепции нужно писать код, чтобы сервер мог обслуживать оба протокола?

На данный момент у меня рабочих идей нет. Типичный `Hello, world` для модуля HTTP выглядит как-то так:

```js
import HTTP from "http";

HTTP.createServer(requestListener).listen(PORT, HOST, (): void => {
  console.log({
    title: "Сервер запущен",
    description: `Ожидание запросов на хост：${HOST}, порт: ${PORT}...`
  });
});
```

Чтобы добавить поддержку HTTPS, нужно прописать аналогичную конструкцию для модуля `HTTPS` и у нас будет-два сервер приложения? Хочется верить, что нет, но если это единственный путь без фреймворков, то я сделаю это.

**Внимание:** ещё раз повторю, что я не прошу рекомендовать никакие фреймворке типа Express. В данном вопросе рассматривается реализация данного функционала без фреймворков.

Comment: Чисто из личного интереса, почему без фреймворков по типу экспресса?

Comment: Формально два, но они оба будут вызывать один и тот же requestListener, так что оверхед будет только на сетевой стек, но он всегда будет

Comment: @OliverPatterson, допустим, он меня не устраивает и я хочу создать свой фреймворк.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, благодарю Вас за комметарий. Позвольте пожалуйста прояснить пару моментов. "будут вызывать один и тот же requestListener" - разве у HTTP и HTTTPS не разные request и response? "оверхед" - что это?

Comment: request и response создаются на каждый запрос, неважно http или https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, два сервиса это - единственный путь. А вот обработчик запросов у них может быть общий!

```
import fs from "fs";
import http from "http";
import https from "https";

const requestListener = (req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse) => {
  console.log(`incoming, ${req.url}`, req.headers);
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello World!');
};

const server1 = http.createServer(requestListener);
const server2 = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.crt')
  },
  requestListener
);

server1.listen(3080, 'localhost',
  () => console.log('HTTP server localhost:3080 was runing...'));
server2.listen(3443, 'localhost',
  () => console.log('HTTPS server localhost:3443 was runing...'));
```

```bsh
$ curl http://localhost:3080/
Hello World!
$ curl https://localhost:3443/
Hello World!
```

---

<sub>Инструкция [как создать самоподписанный сертификат](https://letsencrypt.org/ru/docs/certificates-for-localhost/)</sub>

<sub>Простейший способ добавить самоподписанный сертификат в доверенные на mac os x:</sub>

<sub>`$ sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain localhost.crt`</sub>

---

UPD, в комментариях был задан вопрос:

> Подскажите пожалуйста, а это нормально, что `server2` использует разработчик с параметрами типов `http.IncomingMessage` и `http.ServerResponse`? Эти типы вроде как для `http`.

Тут всё просто - смотрим определения типов (type definitions).

Для модуля `http` [объявлен тип](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a23f844346b0013a6bbc74ef0ddea16c127e815f/types/node/http.d.ts#L124) `RequestListener`

```
type RequestListener = (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => void;
```

и сигнатура функции `createServer`

```
function createServer(requestListener?: RequestListener): Server;
function createServer(options: ServerOptions, requestListener?: RequestListener): Server;
```

А в модуле [`https`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a23f844346b0013a6bbc74ef0ddea16c127e815f/types/node/https.d.ts#L29)

```
import * as http from 'http';
...
function createServer(requestListener?: http.RequestListener): Server;
function createServer(options: ServerOptions, requestListener?: http.RequestListener): Server;
```

Видно, что и для `http`, и для `https` аргумент `requestListener` имеет один и тот же тип - `RequestListener`.